# Help displaying date based on region on ipad app

Tags: ipad, date, localization

In my ipad app the users can enter the date. Is there a way to accept and display the date format for any country the app is being use in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are they entering the date? Are you using UIDatePicker?

NSDateFormatter[1] will respect the current Locale on the phone.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSLog([dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

[1] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateStyle

Comment: Yes its using UIDatePicker. The date wheel comes up when you select the date section and when the user selects the date say yyyy/dd/mm but then appears as mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: The UIDatePicker has its own standardized style for picking a date. There are a few configurable options I believe in IB or via code. The NSDateFormatter will be shown according to locale.

Comment: yes, but how do i get it to stay in the format they entered it in based on the region